# How to order table after SELECT that generates table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically I have a loop in which I change the Number of each value of my table, in the loop I have a variable in order to increase the number of the value, lets call it `@IdTop` where in each iteration of the loop it increases by 1. So I made the loop and now to change each value by order (each value has a sequential number) I made a select top x from table and then select top 1 from that select. So what I want is to order the table that I get from this `SELECT TOP(@IdTop) * FROM tableX WHERE Constraint = 55510` by `ID DESC` and then Select the top 1 from it. This is what I tried but it isn't doing what I want:

```
Select TOP(1) T.ID FROM ((SELECT TOP(3) * FROM tableX WHERE Constraint = 55510) ORDER BY ID DESC) AS T
```

The table has the following values by row for example:

| ID | SequentialNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 3 |
| 134 | 4 |
| 155 | 5 |
| 156 | 2 |
| 180 | 1 |

Example of Iteration:

Iteration 1:
`@IdTop = 1`
Where the ID is 123 the SequentialNumber changes to 1

Iteration 2:
`@IdTop = 2`
Where the ID is 134 the SequentialNumber changes to 2

...

Iteration 5:
`@IdTop = 5`
Where the ID is 180 the SequentialNumber changes to 5

This is the loop that I made:

```
DECLARE @IdTop int = 1
WHILE @IdTop < (Select MAX(SequentialNumber) From OriginalTable WHERE Constraint = 55510) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE OriginalTable SET SequentialNumber = @IdTop WHERE ID = 
    (Select TOP(1) T.ID FROM (SELECT TOP(@IdTop) * FROM OriginalTable WHERE Constraint = 55510 ORDER BY ID DESC) AS T)
    SET @IdTop = @IdTop + 1
END
```

Table after the loop:

| ID | SequentialNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 |
| 134 | 2 |
| 155 | 3 |
| 156 | 4 |
| 180 | 5 |

Comment: I *assume* this is SQL Server, *not* MySQL, as `TOP` is T-SQL syntax.

Comment: Yeah it is, thanks @Larnu

Comment: Can you define your data in TableX and what is expected output from that data?

Comment: Think I put what you wanted @magnus

Comment: @Fr0is, I think you doing a loop for a query that can be done with join, try to change the code using join to update your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this:

```
(Select TOP(1) T.ID 
 FROM (SELECT TOP(@IdTop) * 
       FROM OriginalTable 
       WHERE Constraint = 55510 
       ORDER BY ID DESC
      ) AS T
)
```

is a difficult way of writing:

```
SELECT MAX(T.ID)
FROM OriginalTable
WHERE constraint = 55510
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

The result can also be reached by doing:

```
UPDATE OriginalTable
SET ID = t.R
FROM (SELECT 
   id, 
   row_number() over (order by id) as R
 FROM OriginalTable
 WHERE Constraint = 55510 
) AS T
WHERE T.ID = OriginalTable.ID
```

Comment: Thanks what you wrote did it for me.

Comment: @charlieface: I reversed you changes because they made no sense, and because of the missing comment WHY this change was done.

Comment: Sorry: `...SET ID = t.R (SELECT...` is just not valid SQL, it's missing `FROM`. And my point was: you can update the `T` derived table directly, there is no need to self-join. Which bit didn't make sense?

Comment: I indeed overlooked the fact that `FROM` was missing.     Updating the derived table is also possible, but my knowledge (and experience) with UPDATE-statements is not that good.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) aka CTE instead, like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID int, SeqNr int)

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (123, 3),(134, 4),(155, 5),(156, 2),(180, 1)

SELECT * FROM @tbl ORDER BY ID

;WITH MyFirstCTE AS
    (SELECT ID AS ROW_ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) AS ROW_NUM FROM @tbl)
UPDATE @tbl
SET    SeqNr = ROW_NUM
FROM   MyFirstCTE
WHERE  ID = ROW_ID

SELECT * FROM @tbl ORDER BY ID
```

Output from first SELECT:

```
ID          SeqNr
----------- -----------
123         3
134         4
155         5
156         2
180         1
```

Output from second SELECT:

```
ID          SeqNr
----------- -----------
123         1
134         2
155         3
156         4
180         5
```